# How do you rotate the camera using right mouse clicks with Cinemachine?

Tags: unity, camera, input, cinemachine

How can I rotate the camera around the player using right-click?

Comment: Uhh... Excuse me if I'm missing something unique to Cinemachine but... Right Click Input = lerp to +- 90 degrees on camera?

Comment: [This looks like it's answered in this thread](https://forum.unity.com/threads/whats-the-best-strategy-for-mouse-drag-to-rotate-camera-with-cinemachine-free-look-camera.815355/), just change the mouse button from left (0) to right (1). A search for "cinemachine right-click rotate" turned up this and multiple other guides.